# Max open files on ununtu keeps reseting

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I am migrating from a file based cache to using a MongoDB. I am having issues with he max amount of open files. The mongo daemon keeps crashing because too many files are open. I set the limit of max open files in /etc/sysctl.conf to 500,000. I have set the max open files using ulimit -n 500000 and unlimited. When I do ulimit -n 50000 it says that it updates. [Image for setting limit to 500,000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iItDX.png)

As soon as i close the session, it goes back to the default 1024. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3nyN.png). Even if I start the mongo daemon on that session that says it has the 500,000 open files, it still crashes at the 1,000 file limit.

What should I do to fix this? I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and mongo 3.3.0

Comment: Hang on. What are you doing to mongo that's making it open that many files?

Comment: Its a cache for a stats website. I have 3,000 queries a minute to their database.  I need to cache it on my end. I am building a system to display the top 1000 for a certain thing stat. I have not set indexes yet because I cannot get it to even get that far. It works for smaller tasks such as a specific player's page but it needs to work for everything.

Comment: You're doing _something_ wrong. Lots of people run large MongoDB instances without hitting this limit. (And 50 qps is not particularly high, fwiw.) Are you creating a lot of collections? How large is your database?

Comment: The thing is, there are 'friend list' when people request them, hundreds of caches players are loaded. Often, players have a few hundred friends. I get a friend list request about once a second. Normal player's profiles I get a few a second

Answer (score 0):

Your new session may not get resource limit conf the from pam_limits PAM module. Check your `/etc/pam.d/su` file to see if pam_limits is there.